# Fiori Elements fuzzy search function "contains" on dummy/calculated column CDS View

Tags: sql, abap, hana, sap-fiori, cds

I have a CDS view doing a Union of 2 separate views with different columns/fields.
For example:

```
define view View as

select from A {
   key id,
       firstName
       lastName
}
union all

select from B {
   key id,
       firstName,
       '' as lastName
}
```

I created a consumption view on top of this and added the following annotations to enable the search functionality on the "lastName" field:

```
@Search.defaultSearchElement: true
@Search.fuzzinessThreshold: 1
```

When I run the app and filter using the List Report search bar, it returns me the following error:

> Database returned the SQL code 7. Error text: feature not supported: CONTAINS predicates on expression ''

[image]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Give the code of your consumption view